# VSCode auto-indent (C) after if/while without {}.

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, indentation

I'm working with VSCode and for now I didn't find my answer after walking arround forums for a while now.

I wanted to know if there is a way to have an auto indent while having statement (if/while etc) without adding brace :

```
if (test)
   test;
```

For now i don't have any auto-indent :

```
if (test)
test;
```

I tried several settings already, even on different OS (Windows/Linux).
Thanks you !

Answer (score 1):

File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Editor: Format on Save.

If that doesn't work you probably don't have the C/C++ plugin for VSCode installed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have already C/C++ plugin installed, and even with your settings it's doesn't format at all. However, are you sure that this settings is related to my issue ? I would like to have this indentation on live, not after saving ;)

Comment: @AC my fault:) do you have the options C_Cpp: Clang_format_* in settings? they should be there in Settings -> Extensions -> C/C++.

Comment: Yes, I didn't have the C/C++ Clang plugin installed.